# Data-formatter JavaScript for wenzhixin bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap-table which loads its data from a .json file.  Everything works nicely but I am now trying to add a `data-formatter="winLOSSFormatter"`to one column and can't make that work.

Basically I am looking for it to be a simple `if else` statement that looks at the value and changes the color of the text for that field based on the value.

For example if the value includes the word "win," the text would be green.; the word "loss," the text would be red. Anything else the text would be standard black.

I believe this should be fairly simple to achieve with something along the lines of the script below but I can't seem to make it work.

Thanks!

```
function winLOSSFormatter(value) {
    if (value.indexof ('Win') > -1) {
                color = 'green';
                } else if (value.indexof('Loss') > -1 {
                'red';
                } else {
                 color = 'black';
                };
    return  '<div  style="color: ' + color + '">' + value.substring(1) + '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function winLOSSFormatter(value) {
var color = '#99C262';

if (value.indexOf('W') > -1) {
            color = 'green';
            } else if (value.indexOf('L') > -1) {
            color = 'red';
            } else {
             color = 'black';
            }
return  '<div  style="color: ' + color + '; font-weight: 700;">' + value.substring() + '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had an unclosed bracket at   `} else if (value.indexof('Loss') > -1 {` which was preventing from executing the function. Below is a working code:

```
function winLOSSFormatter(value) {
    if (value.match(/.*Win.*/ig)) {
                var color = 'green';
                } else if (value.match(/.*Loss.*/ig)) {
                'red';
                } else {
                 color = 'black';
                };
    return  '<div  style="color: ' + color + '">' + value + '</div>';
}
```

I am not sure how would you like to handle value like `ThisLossIsMyWinValue`